# Architecture for testable iframe application - Best practices with Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am struggling in seting up a the basic architecture for my **ASP.NET MVC Facebook iframe** application which is running on **Windows Azure**.

I know that there are some basic samples, how to use the toolkit. But it seems that for big application i need a really good architecture to begin developing with.

Also a lot of other developers seem to struggle in setting up this kind of basic architecture for an iframe ASP.NET MVC application, too. So why not gather all available information here and set up something like a starter kit for building complex facebook iframe applications

**Requirements:**

- Highly testable (**Unit Testing** and **Dependency Injection** is a must).
- Runs in Cloud (But also testable locally)
- Supports local debugging

How would you set up an architecture for an **complex facebook application which is testable**?
Does somebody already have a **basic architecture** to start with?

So acutally some of the upcoming **questions** during setting up such an architecture are:

- How to test and debug this applications locally (There seem to be problems with the Windows Azure part)?
- How to develop using Unit Testing (Facebook and Windows Azure Parts needs to be replaced in some form)?
- ...

Since there are so many developers searching for information like that let's set up a starter kit for complex facebook iframe applications which are scalable with cloud but still highly testable locally (I am thinking about the following frameworks: new Facebook C# SDK, AzureToolkit, NUnit and Ninject).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the primary dev and architect of the Facebook C# SDK and the AzureToolkit. We are definitely looking to improve in any way we can. That being said, many of the things you are talking about such as unit testing, local debugging, and building in azure are already supported. We have several apps running in very high load environments that use both the Facebook C# SDK and the AzureToolkit and run on Azure. The other stuff like mocking out Azure and the Facebook APIs are going to be really difficult. If you have some specific ideas on how we could do that, I would love to hear them. The best way to get started with this would be to create a fork of the Facebook C# SDK and start to mock up some of these things. If they work, we will definitely accept them back into the core frameworks.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I am going to investigate further regarding that mocking out part and will tell once/if i have results. The other part is that it would be great to have a bit more (not much more) complex sample using the Facebook and Azure Toolkit which shows the different configurations need for UnitTest, local debugging. I mean which uses some best practices like described here: http://azuretoolkit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=207487

Comment: I agree, that a better sample would be good. I'll talk to Jim Zimmerman about it to see what the plans are for providing a better sample. Regardless though, we always welcome community contributions. Let me know what you come up with. My email is nathan@ntotten.com if you want to get in contact with me that way.

Answer (score 1):

All the Facebook iframe does is provide you with some query parameters that can easily be faked or stubbed inside of your application.  After you remove that complexity you're just building a regular application.